# How to replace only first occurrence of character in CString?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, mfc

I have a `CString st=  $/Abc/cda/($/dba/abc)/`. I want to replace only first occurrence of `$` with `c:\`.

I have tried to replace as

```
st.Replace("$","c:\");
```

But it replaced all occurrence of `$`.

Could you please suggest me any logic to only replace the first occurrence of character.

Comment: What `Replace` is this? Why it's with "R"?

Comment: @MarounMaroun This is MFC [CString::Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztyt5e9c(v=vs.100).aspx), it will replace all occurances of a string or a character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are replacing a single character by three characters, you can use `CString::Find()` and then `CString::Delete()` and `CString::Insert()`, like

```
int nInx = st.Find('$');
if (nInx >= 0)
{    st.Delete(nInx, 1);
     st.Insert(nInx, _T("C:\\");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to replace a character with another character, you could use `SetAt` in conjunction with `FindFirstOf`. `FindFirstOf` will find the index of the first occurrence of the character you want to replace. By passing that as the first argument of `SetAt`, and the replacement character as the second argument, you can replace the first "$" with, say, "#":

```
st.SetAt( st.FindOneOf( "$" ), "#");
```

This doesn't work for the specific case mentioned in the question, though, where you need to replace the "$" character with a multi-character string. For that, you'll need to use [Edward Clements's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17185590).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that encapsulates the accepted answer from Edward Clements:

```
int replaceFirstOf(CString& str, const LPCSTR pszOld, const LPCSTR pszNew)
{
    int found = str.Find(pszOld);
    if (found >= 0)
    {
        str.Delete(found, 1);
        str.Insert(found, pszNew);
    }   
    return found;
}
```